# How to run a spring boot application in intellij?

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am trying to run a spring boot application in intellij 2020.1.1 idea by first generating from spring initializer in [start.spring.io](https://start.spring.io/) then open it with intellij. But when I try the application it doesn't have any output.
[image: run spring boot]

Can anyone help me with this? Is this a problem of windows defender?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Try opening the project using the pom.xml file (instead of the project map). File > Open... > select pom.xml
- Trust the project when asked.
- Run maven when recognized as a maven build.
  (Right now there is no maven tab on the right.)
- When the maven build is recognized a *.iml will be created and a project configuration will be added to your configurations.
- Now you can just press 'run' at the top (or press shift + F10)

Tip: you can also just drag and drop pom files on the start screen and it will open the project.

Comment: How do I open a project using pom.xml file? can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 2):

Click on the run button in Main Class. It will automatically start your project. It worked for me.